# Why is bash completion of a symlink different than a directory?

Tags: find, symlink, utilities

I usually do a `find` with an environment variable as the path when searching for source code. Recently I replaced my environment variable with a symbolic link, and it broke Bash's shell completion. When I do a `find` using the symlink it doesn't work, but if I use the actual path that the symlink points to, it works find.

```
ln -s /some/source/dir /the/source
export SYMLINK=/the/source
export DIR=/some/source/dir

find $SYMLINK -name file.c        // doesn't find anything
find $DIR -name file.c            // works as expected
```

In this example $SYMLINK is a symbolic link for $DIR's value.

So, why does bash handle symlink environment variables differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not bash, it's find; though you'll find that most utilities will follow the same principle:

- If operating on file contents, a symlink to a regular file is equivalent to the actual file.
- If operating on directory entries, symlinks are a category of their own.

When you run `find $SYMLINK`, `find` sees an object that isn't a directory, so it doesn't traverse it. If you want to treat a symlink to a directory as if it was that directory, add a `/` at the end (a few broken systems or commands may require `"$SYMLINK/."`):

```
find "$SYMLINK/" -name file.c
```

For `find`, you can also use the `-H` option, which tells it to treat any symlink on the command line as if you had specified the target:

```
find -H "$SYMLINK" -name file.c
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not `bash`, it's `find`.  Following symlinks in a recursive directory traversal often leads to infinite loops (consider the common trick of `ln -s foo .` to provide a compatibility path).  POSIX `find` includes the `-follow` predicate to override this; perhaps more usefully in this case, GNU find provides `-H` to follow only symlinks directly specified as parameters, while continuing to avoid expanding symlinks found during traversal.  You could use these with an alias:

```
alias find='find -H'
```

Comment: For `-follow` and `-H`, it's the opposite: `-H` is POSIX, `-follow` is a GNU (and other) extension.

Comment: @Gilles: huh, I admit to not checking the POSIX standard specifically but `-follow` predates POSIX.