# find does not work on symlinked path?

Tags: find, symlink, path

If I run this command `find $HOME/MySymlinkedPath -name "run*.sh"` nothing happens, and gives no error ('MySymlinkedPath' is a symlinked path to another hard drive other then my $HOME one).

These also fails:

```
find ~/MySymlinkedPath -name "run*.sh"
find /home/MyUserName/MySymlinkedPath -name "run*.sh"
```

And just to make it sure, this non existent path fails (of course) `find $HOME/MySymlinkedPathDUMMYTEST -name "run*.sh"` so the path is being found (because that error does not happen) but `find` doesn't perform the search on it, and I am a lot clueless now.

It only works if I `cd $HOME/MySymlinkedPath` first and remove the path reference like this `find -name "run*.sh"` but that is not good for my scripts.

**An additional info**:
this command works as usual `ls $HOME/MySymlinkedPath/run*.sh`, and if I go there `cd $HOME/MySymlinkedPath` and run this `ls ..` the result is not what I was expecting -- the list of the path where the symlinked path is located -- it returns the list of the real path on the another media/harddrive!!!

```
pwd -P
/media/MediaIdentifier/RealPath
pwd
/home/MyUser/MySymlinkedPath
```

**Re-thinking**:
Is this a problem with `find` and `ls`, or with my system? or it is expected and not a problem at all?? I am on Ubuntu 12.10. It fails on all terminals I tested so doesn't seems a terminal "problem".

Comment: I found a better answer "find -follow". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105212/linux-recursively-list-all-files-in-a-directory-including-files-in-symlink-direc

Comment: @Jarod man page says -follow is deprecated and we should use -L (that is also --follow) as at my answer below :>

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/why-is-bash-completion-of-a-symlink-different-than-a-directory) is the answer. But that question points to bash as the target of the problem.

The explanation is that `find` finds `"$HOME/MySymlinkedPath"`. It's a symbolic link, not a directory, so the recursive descent stops there. If the expression matched `"$HOME/MySymlinkedPath"` (for example, in `find "$HOME/MySymlinkedPath" -name 'My*'`), then `find` would print that as a match.

As pointed there, I found that the easiest/cleanest way to deal with it and fix all scripts is, instead of:

```
find "$HOME/MySymlinkedPath" -name "run*.sh"
```

just add a slash, so that `find` starts not from the symbolic link but from the target of the symbolic link:

```
find "$HOME/MySymlinkedPath/" -name "run*.sh"
```

Alternatively, pass the `-H` option to `find` (note that it must come first, before the paths) to tell it to traverse symbolic links passed on its command line. (This is different from `-L` which tells `find` to traverse symbolic links encountered during the recursive descent as well.)

```
find -H "$HOME/MySymlinkedPath" -name "run*.sh"
```

And finally it worked best here with `-L` (because of the several filesystems I have symlinked thru folders). But it generates loads of non problematic error messages so I added `2>/dev/null`; and also decided to create this alias `alias find='find -L'`:

```
find -L "$HOME/MySymlinkedPath" -name "run*.sh" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: IMHO, it's generally good practice to use a trailing slash after directories to indicate that they're actually directories. :)  Makes things more readable, etc.

Comment: In case anyone falls into the same trap as me, the position of the -H or -L (and -P -D -O to be complete) flags do matter; it should go before the search path.