# Why existing file is not found with find with `pwd` but is found with find dot?

Tags: find, file-management

This is weird:

```
$ ls -l 'Lana Del Rey - Blue Jeans (Remastered 2011).mp3'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gigi gigi 4.0M Dec 11 23:06 'Lana Del Rey - Blue Jeans (Remastered 2011).mp3'

$ find . -name 'Lana Del Rey - Blue Jeans (Remastered 2011).mp3'
./Lana Del Rey - Blue Jeans (Remastered 2011).mp3

# but still in the same directory:
$ find `pwd` -name 'Lana Del Rey - Blue Jeans (Remastered 2011).mp3'
# nothing found!
# directly using the path pointed by pwd will produce the same nothing-found situation
# with pwd followed by / it works
$ find `pwd`/ -name 'Lana Del Rey - Blue Jeans (Remastered 2011).mp3'
/home/gigi/Music/Youtube_mp3/Lana Del Rey - Blue Jeans (Remastered 2011).mp3
$ pwd
/home/gigi/Music/Youtube_mp3
```

This happens on Ubuntu 21.10 (XUbuntu in fact).
I use no alias overlapping with `find`.

Comment: Are you in a directory whose name contains spaces? Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `pwd` in the relevant directory. Does it work as expected if you run `find "$(pwd)" -name ...` instead?

Comment: I added some new information answering to your question directly or indirectly.

Comment: Is `/home/gigi/Music/Youtube_mp3` a symbolic link? Does `find -H \`pwd\`/ -name 'Lana Del Rey - Blue Jeans (Remastered 2011).mp3'` work?

Comment: I'm sure pwd is a symbolic link.  The shell built in pwd will return the link, where `/bin/pwd` would give the real directory and would work same as `.`; The find `-H` option is probably an easier work around.

Comment: indeed, /home/gigi/Music/Youtube_mp3 is a symbolic link and that was the issue; man, I thought my 7 years old NAS HDD is dying : ) ) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for essentially the same reasons as discussed here:

- [find does not work on symlinked path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93857/find-does-not-work-on-symlinked-path)

In particular, `find` does not traverse symlinks by default - and (at least assuming you are using the bash shell) neither does the builtin `pwd` command. You have a number of options to make the behavior with `pwd` the same as with `.` when the current directory is a symbolic link:

- use the builtin `pwd`, but force resolution of symlinks using `pwd -P`
- use `/bin/pwd` instead of `pwd`; on Ubuntu this will almost certainly be the GNU Coreutils implementation, which assumes `-P` by default
- tell `find` to follow symlinks in its command line arguments, by adding the `-H` command line option.

In the last case, you could use `-L` in place of `-H` however that will follow symlinks everywhere, which may produce results different from `find .`