# /sbin/ctrlaltdel not coming up with whereis?

Tags: bash, fhs

My `$PATH` has `/sbin` in it, and the executable `ctrlaltdel` exists within `/sbin/`. Yet when I run `whereis ctrlaltdel` in the teminal, I do not find `/sbin/ctrlaltdel` The output I get is

```
ctrlaltdel: /usr/sbin/ctrlaltdel /usr/share/man/man8/ctrlaltdel.8.gz
```

Why is this? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.04.

Answer (score 2):

Is /sbin a symbolic link to /usr/sbin?  Modern versions of linux seem to be doing this.

If this is the case, try adding a trailing "/" after the starting point like this:

> find /sbin/ -name ctrlaltdel

[More Details about the find in this Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93857/find-does-not-work-on-symlinked-path)

As for whereis, it's just reporting /usr/sbin because that's actually where ctrlaltdel is located.